# Unable to instantiate application java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:MainApplication

Tags: android

This crash report when I run my Android Application on Android4.4,and my application run it on Android6.0+.
I don't know why this error occured.

Comment: You can check in your manifest , i think you have missed to mentioned class.

Comment: post your application class and AndroidManifest

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling instant run. I was having a similar issue. Once I disabled Instant-Run it started working again.